# how to run chosen webapp on tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications, tomcat8

I've tried to run webapp on tomcat without using IDE (IntelliJ) for the first time.

I deployed .war file of my project in /webapps/ and started tomcat server. I have previously created different webapps on the same 8080 port and I don't really know how to change the priority in which those apps are taking over this port.

I don't really want to change the port, because it's obvious and I was thinking maybe about the right configuration of web.xml file or maybe running a new instance of tomcat without other webapps deployed. I think that creating new instance of a server is too much for now.

Can you tell me is there any way I can choose which webapp will start on port 8080 first?

content of tomcat /webapps:

```
$ ll
total 45
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze  4 21:29 docs/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze  4 21:29 examples/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze  4 21:29 host-manager/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 lip 14 14:32 jspwebapp_war/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze  4 21:29 manager/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze  4 21:29 ROOT/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze 22 13:31 sample/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ThinkPad 197121 4606 cze 22 13:31 sample.war
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 lis  9 22:59 teltuskoDemoApp/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ThinkPad 197121  342 lis  9 21:15 teltuskoDemoApp.war
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 cze 30 10:39 TestowyWebApp/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ThinkPad 197121 2215 cze 22 14:32 TestowyWebApp.war
drwxr-xr-x 1 ThinkPad 197121    0 lip 21 13:46 twitter_war/
```

Some of those projects were made with the help of spring and IntelliJ

My project contins web/index.jsp and also web/WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an application already running in port 8080, another application won't be able to start using port 8080.

You have to terminate the application which is using port 8080, before starting an application using the same port.

I believe the best solution is to start the applications in different ports.

Comment: It's not the point. I'm manually starting tomcat server but it is running different project on port 8080 than I want it to. There are several project deployed in the webapp folder and I would like to know how tomcat is choosing which application will take port 8080 first

Comment: Normally using IDE I don't have to worry about it. It always starts application from project even though there other applications deployed. I would like to learn how to accomplish same results without using IDE